# How to create step line in D3FC seriesWebglLine

Tags: d3.js, next.js, charts, d3fc

I have created a basic lien chart using D3FC and seriesWebglLine. I wanted to have these lines as a step line for a financial chart.

How do I create a step line using vertex shaders and fragment shaders?

Comment: I've manipulated data points, so it can be looked like its step chart. It's just a quick patch and not a proper way but as of now, it's fulfilling the requirements.